# Adobe not prompting for check out and open when PDF files are opened from SharePoint

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, pdf, 2019

I am working with SP on prem 2019 and have set files to launch in client apps by default and it seems to be working fine. Specifically for PDF files, when they are clicked from SharePoint, they launch fine in Adobe reader client but does not prompt for Check out and open.

I have version 2019.012.20036 installed for Adobe.
if anyone came across this, please share thoughts what should be changed so users get prompted for check out and open when PDF launches in Adobe client.

Also FYI, versioning settings-> Require documents to be checked out before editing is set to Yes' . Due to this for all word and excel files, check out and open prompt is working fine but not for PDF files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [Access SharePoint files in Acrobat, Acrobat Reader](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/access-sharepoint-files.html) which also applies to Adobe Acrobat. Rather than opening from SharePoint, open from Adobe by adding an "account" that points to the SharePoint site.

Comment: Appreciate the answer Trevor but that is not something I am looking for.

Comment: This is the approach you need to take as SharePoint doesn't offer this OOTB (and at the same time, PDFs aren't designed to be edited /rant).

Comment: Not sure if u Understood my question currently. In old sp 2013 farm, users were able to open pdf directly in adobe from Sharepoint and it used prompt for check out and open so it’s possible to do but I am not sure how. I have a case open with adobe support as well.

Answer (score 0):

Up until now in our SharePoint 2016 farm, users have received a "Check Out & Open" dialog in Adobe Acrobat when opening PDF files from a SharePoint list (although only when opening via Explorer view in Internet Explorer).

[image: Adobe Acrobat check-out prompt for PDF files in SharePoint]

But after applying January 2021 CU for SP2016 (we were on a very old patch level before), this dialog in Adobe Acrobat has disappeared. It seems to be a common problem.

This guy below has a rather complex solution that he received from a Microsoft support ticket. It involves creating a JavaScript file named PDFFIX.js in the file system on the WFE's and then configuring JSLink settings *on each site collection* to point to this JavaScript file. :(

I have not tested this myself, I am still searching for an easier solution...

https://www.bonzai-intranet.com/blog/checkout-and-open-pdf-files-from-sharepoint-document-libraries/